# Google Sheets Conditional formatting borders - One cell based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create script that automatically adds "blue" lines to an entire row until `column "BY"` based on the value of a cell in a specific column.

### Conditions

When a cell value in Column A (example A4) is different to the value below (example A5), a top thick blue line should be added to cell A6. This conditional formatting starts at row 4 all the way to the end. And should only be applied to specific sheets in the spreadsheet. in Excel I would create the following condition: `=A5<>A4`

### Example

[image]

### SCRIPT THAT WORKS FOR ME

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["FASHION NL", "FASHION BE","KIDS & UNDERWEAR BNL" ,"NEW BUSINESS BNL" ,"SPORTS & SHOES BNL", "HD&E BNL"] // Please set the sheet names.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getRange("H5:H" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const { ranges } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        o.temp = a;
      } else if (i > 0 && o.temp != a) {
        o.ranges.push(`A${i + 5}:BY${i + 5}`);
        o.temp = a;
      }
      return o;
    }, { ranges: [], temp: "" });
    sheet.getRange("A5:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, "GREY", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
  });
}
```

### What if I want to integrate the script above in an existing script?

Goal is to have the conditional formatting run **after** my `autoSortonEdit()` script has finished **AND** it should **only impact** the activesheet from the sorting code. IMPORTANT TO KNOW: the `autoSortonEdit()` function is triggered by edit through Google Sheets.

**Existing script**

```
function autoSortonEdit(e){

  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.getValue() != '') {
    var sheets = ["FASHION NL", "FASHION BE","KIDS & UNDERWEAR BNL" ,"NEW BUSINESS BNL" ,"SPORTS & SHOES BNL", "HD&E BNL"]; // Please set your expected sheet names.
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
      range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
      e.source.toast('Sort complete.');

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the blue border line from column "A" to column "BY", when the value of column "A" is changed. And, you want to start from row 5, and also, first, you want to put the borderline to the top of row 5.
- You want to use this script for the specific sheets you expect.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getRange("A5:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const { ranges } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        o.temp = a;
      } else if (i > 0 && o.temp != a) {
        o.ranges.push(`A${i + 5}:BY${i + 5}`);
        o.temp = a;
      }
      return o;
    }, { ranges: [], temp: "" });
    sheet.getRange("A5:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  });
}
```

- In your sample Spreadsheet image, the border is put from column "A" to column "C". But, from your question of `I am trying to create script that automatically adds "blue" lines to an entire row until column "BY" based on the value of a cell in a specific column.`, when this script is run your sample Spreadsheet, the same borders are put from column "A" to column "BY".
- In this script, by `sheet.getRange("A5:BY").setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);`, the initial borders of "A5:BY" are cleared and new borders are put. If you don't want to clear the existing borders, please remove this line.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal,-color,-style)

Comment: Thank you, However I don't want row 5 to have the top borderline. This should start from row 6.

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `However I don't want row 5 to have the top borderline. This should start from row 6.`, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet image, it seems that the border line is put to the top of row 5. Can I ask you about your actual expected result?

Comment: @Diego Kersjes About `However I don't want row 5 to have the top borderline. This should start from row 6.`, if you don't want to put the borderline to the top of row 5, for example, when you remove `o.ranges.push("A5:BY5");` from my proposed script, is that your expected result? If I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your actual goal? By this, I would like to modify my sample script.

Comment: Also how can I just clear the initial HORIZONTAL borders before the new border are put? I want to keep the vertical ones.

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. About your new request of `Also how can I just clear the initial HORIZONTAL borders before the new border are put? I want to keep the vertical ones.`, I would like to recommend resolving from your initial issue in order. Because from your 1st reply, I cannot still understand your actual goal. In this case, I cannot resolve your new request. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Diego Kersjes From this current situation, your initial issue was resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. I understood it. About your new request of `Also how can I just clear the initial HORIZONTAL borders before the new border are put? I want to keep the vertical ones.`, in this case, when you modify `sheet.getRange("A5:BY").setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);` to `sheet.getRange("A5:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);`, is that your expected result?

Comment: It works! Thanks again. Last thing.. Please see my updated question

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved.

Comment: Did you see my 3rd question too? :-)

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. About your 3rd question of `Did you see my 3rd question too? :-)`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?