# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting of Borders Only for Visible Rows (not filtered rows)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering, border, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to add dynamic horizontal borders to visually group rows. Here is an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1poSUt5QzvPG5VmVXmChaO0NKkCq5qdwWzZCw_NNpA1U/edit#gid=0) that shows what I'm trying to do. Basically, I need to apply a horizontal border whenever the value in column A changes, but I want to apply this to only the *visible* rows.

I used this function which works well assuming all rows are visible, but doesn't work if you filter out or hide one of the rows where the value changes:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["Grade 6","Grade 7","Grade 8","Algebra 1","Algebra 2","Geometry"]; // Please set the sheet names.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const { ranges } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        o.temp = a;
      } else if (i > 0 && o.temp != a) {
        o.ranges.push(`A${i + 2}:BY${i + 2}`);
        o.temp = a;
      }
      return o;
    }, { ranges: [], temp: "" });
    sheet.getRange("A2:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  });
}
```

I'd like the border to appear between the *visible* rows, even when filtered or hidden (for example, in the "Desired Output" sheet where rows with "C" are filtered). Does anyone have any reasonably simple way to help achieve this? I'm pretty new with scripts so I'm trying to piece it together in a way that allows me to edit it myself.

Comment: You say `I need to apply a horizontal border whenever the value in column A changes,` don't you mean to say where column B changes.  That's what you're code is looking at

Comment: Whoops, I copy/pasted the code from the actual sheet I'm editing rather than making it for the example sheet. Fixed now.

Comment: From your showing script, if you had used [my sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897203), I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From your provided Spreadsheet, I modified my script and posted it as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script and your provided Spreadsheet, I guessed that you might have used [my sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897203). If my understanding is correct, in order to achieve your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["Grade 6","Grade 7","Grade 8","Algebra 1","Algebra 2","Geometry"]; // Please set the sheet names.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const { ranges } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        o.temp = a;
      } else if (i > 0 && o.temp != a && !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 2)) { // Modified
        o.ranges.push(`A${i + 2}:BY${i + 2}`);
        o.temp = a;
      }
      return o;
    }, { ranges: [], temp: "" });
    sheet.getRange("A2:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  });
}
```

- When I tested this modified script to your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the same result with "Desired Output" could be obtained as follows.

  [image]
- In your showing script, `sheet.getRange("A2:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);` is used. If you want to achieve the same situation with "Desired Output" sheet, you might want to remove `sheet.getRange("A2:BY").setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false);`.

#### Reference:

- [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified it a bit to change background color on data changes in B.  If you filter a line out the backgrounds for the rest of the data will still remain.  It I am wrong then I apologize for misunderstanding what your goal is.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sns = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1"];
  const cs = ["#ffffff", "#cccccc"]
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sns.forEach(sn => {
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sn);
    const range = sh.getRange("B3:B" + sh.getLastRow());
    range.getValues().flat().reduce((o, a, i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        o.pastA.push(a);
        o.pastC.push(0);
        sh.getRange(`A${i + 3}:P${i + 3}`).setBackground(cs[o.pastC[o.pastC.length - 1]])
      }
      if (i > 0 && o.pastA[o.pastA.length - 1] != a) {
        sh.getRange(`A${i + 3}:P${i + 3}`).setBackground(cs[(o.pastC[o.pastC.length - 1] + 1) % 2]);
        o.pastA.push(a);
        o.pastC.push(((o.pastC[o.pastC.length - 1] + 1) % 2))
      } else {
        sh.getRange(`A${i + 3}:P${i + 3}`).setBackground(cs[(o.pastC[o.pastC.length - 1])]);
      }
      return o;
    }, { ranges: [], pastA: [], pastC: [] });
  });
}
```